# Aside from the Rings of Power, what else did Sauron make in his forge at Mount Doom?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-one-ring, sauron

We know that the forging power of Mount Doom was legendary and vastly powerful. And I see from other questions here that Sauron kept the forge at Mount Doom essentially crafting *things*.

My question is, ***excluding the One Ring and the other Lesser Rings of Power*,  are there any other named artifacts in Lord of the Rings and Middle Earth Lore that are attributed to Sauron's craftsmanship or specifically tied to the Mount Doom Forge?**

I think it would be awesome to do some fan fiction about a quest for one of these *other* legendary items that maybe has nothing to do with the One Ring, and could even be written as a side note to the events of the Fellowship.

Comment: He created the Silver Spork of Devouring at Mount Doom.

Comment: @anaranjada - I'd be willing to bet that he made that [nifty hat](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/a9/2f/41/a92f415398a190a2bc17b5c90fd75d4c.jpg).

Comment: Now that I look at it, the accepted answer on the first duplicate question might answer this new question.

Comment: @anaranjada - I don't think so. That answers the question of why he kept it open (to make stuff). This is asking "What stuff?".

Comment: I'm not sure the last paragraph adds anything to the question. I was tempted to just edit it out entirely.

Comment: @anaranjada Badminton rackets. Those Urûks were *fiends* on the court.

Comment: @JoshuaA Sounds like you may need to just make something up for your fan fiction.

Comment: He made *prototypes* of Rings of Power.

Comment: @anaranjada - In the Shadow of Mordor game, Sauron's **Hammer** (the [big one](http://www.eigenspace.net/robot/mace/mace1.JPG), not the [little one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/b4ZSd.png)) is [imbued with dark magics](https://youtu.be/Wn2fxgpnuZU?t=2m3s). It seems highly likely that it was forged in Sauron's workshop.

Comment: Note that there doesn't need to be anything particularly special about Mount Doom aside from being a source of perpetual heat.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Nothing we know of

There are rather few mentions of Mount Doom. A few of those, to my knowledge, mention the forging of objects there, but always the Ruling Ring:

> There above the valley of Gorgoroth was built his fortress vast and
> strong, Barad-dûr, the Dark Tower; and there was a fiery mountain in
> that land that the Elves named Orodruin. Indeed for that reason Sauron
> had set there his dwelling long before, for he used the fire that
> welled there from the heart of the earth in his sorceries and in his
> forging; and in the midst of the Land of Mordor he had fashioned the
> Ruling Ring.
>
> —*The Silmarillion*

Similarly,

> ‘Alas! yes,’ said Elrond. ‘Isildur took it, as should not have been.
> It should have been cast then into Orodruin’s fire nigh at hand where
> it was made.
>
> —*The Fellowship of the Ring*

Note that the first quote makes it clear that Sauron used Mount Doom in many of his other works, but what they are is not mentioned.

Whatever weapons and armor Sauron and his lieutenants wore *could* have been forged in Orodruin, but there is no proof thereof.

As mentioned by @anaranjada, the battering ram Grond may have been forged in Mount Doom, but again, we don't know:

> Fires leaped up. Great engines crawled across the field; and in the
> midst was a huge ram, great as a
> forest-tree a hundred feet in length, swinging on mighty chains. Long
> had it been forging in the dark smithies of Mordor, and its hideous
> head, founded of black steel, was shaped in the likeness of a ravening
> wolf; on it spells of ruin lay. Grond they named it, in memory of the
> Hammer of the Underworld of old.
>
> —*The Return of the King*

I believe that Sauron's mace is film-only, but even in that case we don't know where it was forged!

Answer (score 8):

**No**

There are no other named items that were forged in Mount Doom.
We can assume that his armor, helm and weapons were forged there as well, but they are not named.

Only the One ring and the lesser rings are explicitly linked to Mount Doom.

Source: *The LoTR trilogy, The Silmarillion and The Children of Hurin*

Comment: What about his mace? Does that have a history?

Comment: None that I'm aware of.

Comment: [This answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48641/why-did-sauron-keep-mount-doom-alive-after-forging-of-the-one-ring/48643#48643) suggests that the battering ram Grond could have been created at Mount Doom. Is there any indication of that in the text?

Comment: Again, not as far as I know. We know it was forged in Mordor, but that doesn't say much. We know for sure that there are many other ''regular'' forges in Mordor.