What was the significance of Mount Doom's eruption?
One of the names for the famous volcano in Mordor is "Amon Amarth" apparently meaning "Mount Doom" or "Mount Destiny". Tolkien Gateway says that it got the name in the following way:

The mountain erupted in S.A. 3429, signalling Sauron's attack on Gondor and it took the name Amon Amarth, "Mount Doom".

Does this naming mean that there was some kind of causal link between these events? Or did they happen at the same time by pure coincidence?

Destiny kinda precludes pure coincidence ;) Maybe just ask what's the connection...

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48641/why-did-sauron-keep-mount-doom-alive-after-forging-of-the-one-ring

There was probably no causal relationship between the two. The eruption appears to have occurred after the attacks
The Tale of Years (Appendix B) does not mention Mount Doom for the year of 3429; it simply describes Sauron's attack on Gondor in that year.
However, Appendix A includes this about Sauron and Mount Doom:

Therefore, after a time he made war upon the Exiles, before they should take root. Orodrúin burst once more into flame, and was named anew in Gondor Amon Amarth, Mount Doom.

This helpful Reddit thread notes that Mount Doom erupted after previous actions by Sauron:

Turgon followed Túrin, but of his time it is chiefly remembered that two years ere his death, Sauron arose again, and declared himself openly; and he re-entered Mordor long prepared for him. Then Barad-dûr was raised once more, and Mount Doom burst into flame.

Together this seems to imply that the eruptions signal that Sauron is openly active, suggesting that Sauron is using the eruptions as an intimidation tool - in both cases, after the initial attacks, not before.
I'd have to say that it's natural for the Men of the West to decide that the dramatic eruption of a mountain in the land of their Enemy at about the same time as other terrible events (a deadly attack on Gondor which destroyed the White Tree) was bad news, and thus reasonably prompted the change of the name to Mount Doom.

I don't think that JRRT provides a clear answer.
There are really just two main possibilities:

Mt Doom is just a volcano that certainly has been used by Sauron (not just for forging the One Ring. It's an important enough tool for him that when the road to Mt Doom is "...blocked or destroyed by the tumults of the Mountain's furnaces, [it is] repaired and cleaned again by the labours of countless orcs") but which does not erupt at his command. Sauron is one of the Ainur who sang Arda into being, and before he fell into corruption -- which inevitably diminished him -- he may well have had the strength to make it go boom. But he lost a great deal of his power when he forged and then lost the Ring, and when he was caught up in the Fall of Numenor and the war with the Last Alliance.

Mt. Doom erupts in sympathy with Sauron who, either deliberately or as a side-effect of the awful magics workings he performed there, has linked the mountain to himself. Mt Doom consequently erupts at times of Sauron's great exertion or stress.


Valorum's prodding led me to remember that we do have one instance where Sauron seems to have influenced the volcano: The great clouds of smoke poured out of Mt. Doom which plunged northern Gondor into darkness for the assault on Minas Tirith. It's impossible not to see this as caused by Sauron to aid his war.
A weak argument in favor of this option can be made by drawing a parallel between Sauron and Morgoth who certainly did make his mountains (both Thangorodrim and the Iron Mountains) erupt with fire as part of his war effort.  But Morgoth was more powerful than any of the Valar, while my the Third Age Sauron was a weak Maiar.
Unfortunately, JRRT -- due to his policy of not over-explaining the numinous -- has not told us enough to choose convincingly between those options.
(There are, of course, sub options including the possibility that the records are wrong or misleading. It would be completely unsurprising if later studies by the Gondorian Geological Society were to discover that Mt Doom tended to erupt once a decade on average so that the coincidences only seem surprising because unportentous eruptions -- the most common kind -- have been long forgotten.)
== Added Later after Comments ==
Two comments have caused me to refine my conclusion. @Aphelli reminded me that in the climactic scene,

And far away, as Frodo put on the Ring and claimed it for his own, even in Sammath Naur the very heart of his realm, the Power in Barad-dûr was shaken, and the Tower trembled from its foundations to its proud and bitter crown. The Dark Lord was suddenly aware of him

makes it completely clear that there was some deep connection between Sauron and Mt. Doom beyond the happenstance that he used its heat for a forge.
I think it is still true that Tolkien did not tell us enough to prove that Sauron's wars caused the eruptions of Mt. Doom (I think we can ignore the reverse that eruptions of Mt Doom, cause Sauron to go to war...)
Revised bottom line: There is definitely some sort of link between Sauron and Mt. Doom, but we are not told enough to say much more than that. But whether Sauron caused the eruptions or if they were some sort of side-effect, I don't think we can say.

Some quotes would turn this from good into great.

@Valorum I wish! But I can't find much, really. Tolkien does not seem to have said anything.  (It's true that Morgoth with his "heats immoderate" certainly could have made Mt. Doom erupt any time he wanted to, but Morgoth was more powerful than any of the Valar, while there is not reason to believe that Sauron was more than an average Maiar.)  I will add that and I will note also that the clouds pout out by Mt. Doom for the assault on Minas Tirith do seem to have been an action of Sauron.

I think Tolkien also says it’s dark in the volcano because of Sauron’s power, and even Galadriel’s light cannot help Frodo and Sam when they arrive there.

I sort of imagine Sauron doing his weird incantations at the crack of doom, then dumping a huge load of used tyres in there ;)

Is "pretentious" in the last sentence a typo / autocorrect-ism for "portentous"?

I think a combination of the two is most likely. The volcano doesn't need to be linked to Sauron, but whatever he does there could easily cause an eruption as a side effect or result. (I was about to add this as a comment to the other answer, but then I saw that you addressed my thinking more directly.)

@chepner I think you are right, and I have modified my answer accordingly. (Apologies if changing the root nature of an answer is considered inappropriate.)

I think you handled it appropriately, adding your opinion on our comments rather than removing the original content. (+1, btw; I'm not sure why I didn't upvote earlier, but I have now :) )
